# How to Store Widgets in a List Properly to Return in a Widget Class

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new in Flutter. I know that in Widget class you can only return once. I'm using For Loop and want to add it into a List so that I can return it.

My code:

```
Widget _blacklistInfos() {
Map<String, dynamic> mapScan = jsonDecode(scanRaw);
var widgetsList = List<Widget>();
if (scanRaw.contains('{"BLACKLIST":{"INFO":[')) {
  for (int x = 0; x < mapScan['BLACKLIST']['INFO'].length; x++) {
    print('a');
    widgetsList.add(
      Card(
        child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          title: Text(mapScan['BLACKLIST']['INFO'][x][0]),
          subtitle: Text(mapScan['BLACKLIST']['INFO'][x][1]),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
          onTap: () async {
            await launch(mapScan['BLACKLIST']['INFO'][x][1]);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  return ListView(children: widgetsList);
} else {
  return SizedBox.shrink();
}
}
```

Is there anyway to do this properly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not too bad. I'd apply the following changes:

- For readability (and safety), use "map" instead of "for", like this:

```dart
var blackListEntries = mapScan['BLACKLIST']['INFO'].map((entry) => Card(...))
```

- maybe omit the `return SizedBox.shrink();` - you can also just return a ListView with empty children list